# I need to update my application on google play but could not due to error. I cant figure out the bug

Tags: android

I was trying to update my apps on Google play store. , but it shows like the picture. What can I do? 
here is the image http://prntscr.com/4ikc9x

Answer (score 0):

In version 1 there' set minSDKVersion = 9 and in version 2 minSDKVersion = 3 . So this problem arrived. It should be an Google ads api compatibility problem. You may able to show google ads from API 9 to latest.